# Who is responsible for the subdomains in different scenarios?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router, subdomain

I want sub domains in my SPA made with React, but I'm not sure how this works.

When I was searching for subdomains in a Django project, they said that Nginx (Read nginx as HTTP server, nginx is just a preference over Apache and others) is preferred for this. But, I have not yet switched on nginx, and I do not know how it works.

There is also another point: I think I will serve my SPA in amazon S3, and how it serves only static files, what would the subdomains look like? can the react-router do this? obs: I still do not know which one to use: s3 or github pages.

I do not need to know about how sub domains work in back-end apps for now, but you can also explain that it will help me.

Here are some examples of what I want:

domain.com/blog/2019/some-article-title
-> blog.domain.com/2019/some-article-title

domain.com/myusername 
-> myusername.domain.com

domain.com/myusername/settings 
-> myusername.domain.com/settings

Comment: I did something like what u say with apache and it calls reverse proxy. u can find the guide and read about how it works here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html , it is actually pretty easy, u have to create a virtualhost and set ur subdomain url as a reverse proxy to ur main domain path or whatever u want. I think it won't be much difference in nginx

Answer (score 0):

in apache we can also use `.htaccess` files to redirect the urls to another one, almost something like what u want to do (but not quite) and we don't need to change the server settings but in nginx I think u have to edit some of ur config files.

as I said in my comment, u can use reverse proxies and also u can use redirection (for example for ur React routings. I am not a react developer but u can see some example here for angular (just for getting the point): https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples)

by a little search, I found this article that explains what is a reverse proxy is and how u can do it, hope it helps:
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/